# trouble implementing django search bar site wide

Tags: python, django, forms

I am very new to forms with django. I have this method in my views.py:

```
def search(request):
register.inclusion_tag('blog/search.html')(search)
template = loader.get_template('blog/search.html')
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Search(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/search/?'+request.POST)
else
    form = Search()
context = Context({
                'form':form
                })
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Corresponding to this form class:

```
from django import forms

class Search(forms.form):
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=65)
```

Then in my template I have

```
{% search %}
```

Now I know that I am a train wreck... But I really need some guidance. This search bar exists sitewide. Please help me out. I am getting a very generic error message indicating there is something wrong with my urls.py module. However, I know that is not the case because before I started building the search portion, it worked well.

The point of the script is to display something along the lines of:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" />
```

According to the Django documentation.

Thank you in advance,
Biggest Noob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There a few issues with this - starting of with the fact that `register.inclusion_tag` is for custom template tags, which have to be in a specific directory structure.

So what I understand is you are creating a custom template tag, which will render your search form anywhere in any template, by using `{% search %}`.

Now you can create a custom tag, or you can simply add the form in your base template and using template inheritance make sure that the form shows up in every page.  My suggestion is to create a standard search form, add it to your base template (any template that every other template will inherit from). This is typically called _*base.html* but it can be called anything.

So first, you write the view:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        # There was a query entered.
        results = SomeModel.objects.filter(somefield=query)
    else:
        # If no query was entered, simply return all objects
        results = SomeModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'search_result.html', {'results': results})
```

Next, wire it up in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^search/$', 'app.views.search','search'),
```

Finally, add it to your form (which is in _*base.html*):

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}">
      <input type="text" name="q" />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```